# Curl copied from chrome devtools, yields different response in terminal. Javascript rendered web site

Tags: javascript, curl, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to perform a job search on glassdoor and crawl the results. Here's the first [page](https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/python-jobs-SRCH_KO0,6.htm?Autocomplete=) of an example search. The second page results are obtained using a fetch request which is triggered by clicking the next button.

Here's the curl sent by the browser after clicking the next button:

```
curl 'https://www.glassdoor.com/graph' \
  -H 'authority: www.glassdoor.com' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8' \
  -H 'apollographql-client-name: job-search' \
  -H 'apollographql-client-version: 0.27.22' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'cookie: ...' \
  -H 'gd-csrf-token: ...' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.glassdoor.com' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.glassdoor.com/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw '{"operationName":"JobSearchQuery","variables":{"searchParams":{"keyword":"python","numPerPage":30,"searchType":"SR","pageNumber":2,"pageCursor":"AB4AAYEAHgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMLZPsAPwEBAQ0EQ8ADTE5cfDqxexbrGvagYDN+iOmE8v7CeRN5VA9AB6c4BP2LZ3F1cbEmTsNtyle+DW0dPbIa5HyzwQAA","filterParams":[{"filterKey":"includeNoSalaryJobs","values":"true"},{"filterKey":"sc.keyword","values":"python"},{"filterKey":"locT","values":""},{"filterKey":"locId","values":""}],"seoUrl":false}},"query":"query JobSearchQuery($searchParams: SearchParams) {\n  jobListings(contextHolder: {searchParams: $searchParams}) {\n    ...SearchFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment SearchFragment on JobListingSearchResults {\n  adOrderJobLinkImpressionTracking\n  totalJobsCount\n  filterOptions\n  companiesLink\n  searchQueryGuid\n  indeedCtk\n  jobSearchTrackingKey\n  paginationCursors {\n    pageNumber\n    cursor\n    __typename\n  }\n  searchResultsMetadata {\n    cityPages {\n      cityBlurb\n      cityPagesStats {\n        bestCitiesForJobsRank\n        meanBaseSalary\n        population\n        unemploymentRate\n        __typename\n      }\n      displayName\n      employmentResources {\n        addressLine1\n        addressLine2\n        cityName\n        name\n        phoneNumber\n        state\n        zipCode\n        __typename\n      }\n      heroImage\n      isLandingExperience\n      locationId\n      numJobOpenings\n      popularSearches {\n        text\n        url\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    copyrightYear\n    footerVO {\n      countryMenu {\n        childNavigationLinks {\n          id\n          link\n          textKey\n          __typename\n        }\n        id\n        link\n        textKey\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    helpCenterDomain\n    helpCenterLocale\n    isPotentialBot\n    jobAlert {\n      jobAlertExists\n      promptedOnJobsSearch\n      promptingForJobClicks\n      __typename\n    }\n    jobSearchQuery\n    loggedIn\n    searchCriteria {\n      implicitLocation {\n        id\n        localizedDisplayName\n        type\n        __typename\n      }\n      keyword\n      location {\n        id\n        localizedDisplayName\n        shortName\n        localizedShortName\n        type\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    showMachineReadableJobs\n    showMissingSearchFieldTooltip\n    __typename\n  }\n  companyFilterOptions {\n    id\n    shortName\n    __typename\n  }\n  pageImpressionGuid\n  pageSlotId\n  relatedCompaniesLRP\n  relatedCompaniesZRP\n  relatedJobTitles\n  resourceLink\n  seoTableEnabled\n  jobListingSeoLinks {\n    linkItems {\n      position\n      url\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  jobListings {\n    jobview {\n      job {\n        descriptionFragments\n        eolHashCode\n        jobReqId\n        jobSource\n        jobTitleId\n        jobTitleText\n        listingId\n        __typename\n      }\n      gdJobAttributes {\n        salarySource\n        basePay {\n          p25\n          p75\n          __typename\n        }\n        additionalPay {\n          p25\n          p75\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      jobListingAdminDetails {\n        adOrderId\n        cpcVal\n        importConfigId\n        jobListingId\n        jobSourceId\n        userEligibleForAdminJobDetails\n        __typename\n      }\n      overview {\n        id\n        name\n        shortName\n        squareLogoUrl\n        __typename\n      }\n      gaTrackerData {\n        trackingUrl\n        jobViewDisplayTimeMillis\n        requiresTracking\n        isIndeedJob\n        searchTypeCode\n        pageRequestGuid\n        isSponsoredFromJobListingHit\n        isSponsoredFromIndeed\n        __typename\n      }\n      header {\n        adOrderId\n        adOrderSponsorshipLevel\n        advertiserType\n        ageInDays\n        applyUrl\n        autoLoadApplyForm\n        easyApply\n        easyApplyMethod\n        employerNameFromSearch\n        jobLink\n        jobCountryId\n        jobResultTrackingKey\n        locId\n        locationName\n        locationType\n        needsCommission\n        normalizedJobTitle\n        organic\n        payPercentile90\n        payPercentile50\n        payPercentile10\n        hourlyWagePayPercentile {\n          payPercentile90\n          payPercentile50\n          payPercentile10\n          __typename\n        }\n        rating\n        salarySource\n        sponsored\n        payPeriod\n        payCurrency\n        savedJobId\n        sgocId\n        categoryMgocId\n        urgencySignal {\n          labelKey\n          messageKey\n          normalizedCount\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n"}' \
  --compressed
```

which if executed directly in a terminal, for some reason despite having worked in the browser, I get a human verification message, which indicates something went wrong:

```
<h1>Help Us Protect Glassdoor</h1>
<p>
    Please help us protect Glassdoor by verifying that you're a
    real person. We are sorry for the inconvenience. If you continue to see this 
    message, please email
</p>
```

This sort of work should be available through the [api](https://www.glassdoor.com/developer/register_input.htm) which is clearly having issues / not working since I keep getting a

```
Glassdoor will not work properly unless browser cookie support is enabled
```

despite the cookies being enabled. So, what I'm trying to do is figure out how to make the curl work outside the browser, then I will repeat whatever works for getting the subsequent results.

**Note:** I'm aware this can be easily achieved using `selenium` which I'm currently using to get the search results. I don't like the selenium approach because it's slow and not sure about whether this can be achieved without javascript. If I get the `curl` approach to work, it easily be converted to a python `requests` approach which would be the optimal result.

Answer (score 1):

The website use [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to render the web page.

You can test by yourself when you have doubt:

In `firefox`, open a tab `about:config`, then double click: `javascript.enabled`, it become `False`. Then refresh web page:

[image: warning]
**you don't have expected datas**.

To fetch datas, you need a library that is `JavaScript` aware. Could be one of :

- `Python`, `JavaScript` or `Java` + [`Selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/)
- `Python` + [`Playwright`](https://playwright.dev/)
- `Python` + [`request-HTML`](https://github.com/psf/requests-html)
- `JavaSript` [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) + [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev)

With the later, you can use this script as a replacement for `cURL`:
we need to fake the [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) to be able to retrieve datas:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    var url = process.argv[2];
    if (!url) {
        console.error('Usage: ' + process.argv[1] + ' <URL>');
        process.exit(1);
    }
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36");
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    const html = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML);
    console.log(html);
    browser.close();
})()
```

Then use:

```
node wget.js 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/python-jobs-SRCH_KO0,6.htm' > glassdoor.html
html2text glassdoor.html
```

As you can figure out, it's a specific IT domain, it's named [web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping), I can be hired to do the job as needed to render datas as clean `CSV`, `JSON`, `MongoDB`, or anything™. This is my specialty.

---

Another solution would be to use `Python` + `requests`, sometimes is sufficient, even if it's not `Javascript` capable. But you have to dig into `Chrome Dev Tools`, and try to figure out which request can generate by example a `JSON` or your needed `HTML`.

Comment: I think I had to mention this in the question as well. I was originally fetching the search results with `python` + `selenium`, and since I don't like it since it's quite slow, I decided to go with a python + `requests` approach. I then tried this approach and was able to get the 30 urls on the first page without using any javascript. So I assumed there must be a way to avoid using javascript. That's when I tried the `curl` approach and if it works for the subsequent pages, I can simply convert `curl` to `requests`.

Comment: Post edited accordingly to mention requests as well

Comment: My main issue is managing to get the subsequent page results without having to use a javascript approach which includes `selenium` or your `puppeteer ` approach. It's still unclear to me how to do so using `curl`  which is the main goal of the question or python `requests`.

Comment: Do you know what's takes the most time in web scraping with Selenium? Loading images, or hard-coded sleep. If you disable image loading, it will be fast. No need to have headaches with requests in this case when Selenium is so easy. Depends of the needs.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll probably go with the selenium approach so I will disable images and any other unnecessary content. The problem with selenium is its bad implementation, it doesn't necessarily fail but does many simple things inefficiently. I was once using it to parse facebook comments, it required 2 seconds per comment (to just extract the comment value). I replaced the `driver.find_elements` approach with a `lxml.html` approach which resulted in parsing all 50 comments in 0.something seconds. It has many other issues as well that's why I don't use it unless there's no other way.

Comment: https://pptr.dev have the same functionalities, but is faster. If you already have the selectors and the logic, you just have to 'port' the code to Async JS (NodeJS)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Python` `requests` (no need [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) in this special case):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
  
session = requests.session()

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

page = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/python-jobs-SRCH_KO0,6.htm?Autocomplete='
res = session.get(page, headers=headers)
res.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(res.text)
```

Then, to go to next page, you need to pass the `JSON` object that the website does with `requests` in a `POST` request to `https://www.glassdoor.com/graph`.

You can see this request in Chrome Dev Tools: Network tab.

It's a very big `JSON`.

Comment: My problem is not the knowing how to get the first page results using `requests`. The main objective as I indicated earlier in the question and other comments is to get the second page, the third and so on ... without having to use javascript.

Comment: Added explanations about passing the JSON object. I's a profession ;)