# Python with Selenium/BS4 - Being detected at first request. How can I determine if crawling/scraping is possible?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, bots, web-crawler

I'm trying to extract data from the site https://drizly.com for my project.
I tried to make a request and load a soup object and also tried to use selenium.
But, the site blocks my requests.
How can I determine if crawling/scraping is possible for the site?
Robot txt was not available and returned Error code 1020

`load_soup` function output is different than the HTML data of the actual URL.

```py
def load_soup(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup
```

The selenium use was also very basic and seem to open the site normally at first, But got blocked pretty quickly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl copied from chrome devtools, yields different response in terminal. Javascript rendered web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76232995/curl-copied-from-chrome-devtools-yields-different-response-in-terminal-javascr) **Your site is JavaScript rendered**.