# How to check if a credential is correct with wget? (javascript rendered forms)

Tags: javascript, wget

I'm trying to use wget to check if a login was succeed or failed. But instead I'm getting code 200 even when I input the wrong username or password:

```
wget --user=username --password=password -O myfile https://example.com
```

Any idea how to make this works? Thanks.

I tried:

```
wget --user=myusername --password=mypassword https://my.min-fx.tv/login -S --delete-after
```

ETA: the webpage is javascript

Comment: It's a javascript login. If you disable javascript in the browser, you will see you can't submit the forms

Comment: Check [Javascript capable libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76236342/465183) or hire a web scraper (I do)

Comment: Is there a particular text from output HTML in case of good credentials?

Comment: In my cases its always output code 200 no matter what the credentials are, or no credentials at all. I'm malding

Comment: I don't care the http return code I ask the **output** in text or HTML: `wget -O- https://........` with **good credentials**

Answer (score -3):

the option is --user and --ask-password wget will ask for the credentials. Below is an example.

```
wget --user=username --ask-password -O myfile https://example.com
```

check here : [What is the correct wget command syntax for HTTPS with username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595554/what-is-the-correct-wget-command-syntax-for-https-with-username-and-password)

Comment: The page is javascript rendered. Not possible to send request. And this is not an answer. The mininum is to copy the code. OP already knows how to send user/password, this is not the question

Comment: where did you see a JS rendered here ?  and i put the to where i found the right solution for him don't decrease the answer like the tag is for linux.

Comment: Test to go to login page and disable javascript: in Firefox `about:config` : `javascript.enabled == False`, then refresh, try to send the forms. Nothing happens. Not possible via `wget` IMHO.